# How do I code these relationships in sql without getting am error

Tags: sql, database, database-design, db2, entity-relationship

Attached is my attempt at creating a database for the following entity relationship diagram. But I keep getting the following error:

> "SQL0538N  FOREIGN KEY "ADVISOR_STUDENT" does not conform to the
>   description of the parent key of table or nickname "KISHANPA.STUDENT".
>   SQLSTATE=42830"

for these 4 tables: advisor, prereq, teaches, takes. The rest of the tables seem to work fine. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can guide me int eh right direction. Thanks

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBTGC.jpg)

[Schema Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwxd1.jpg)

```
create table department (
  dept_name varchar(30) not null, 
  building varchar(30), 
  budget numeric(7,2), 
  constraint department_key primary key (dept_name)
);

create table instructor (
  iid char(9) not null, 
  name varchar(30) not null, 
  dept_name varchar(30) not null, 
  salary numeric(6,2), 
  constraint instructor_key primary key (iid, dept_name), 
  constraint instructor_dept foreign key(dept_name) 
      references department on delete no action
);

create table student (
  sid char(9) not null, 
  name varchar(30) not null, 
  tot_cred smallint, 
  dept_name varchar(30) not null, 
  constraint student_key primary key (sid, dept_name), 
  constraint student_dept foreign key(dept_name) 
      references department on delete no action
);

create table course (
  course_id char(8) not null, 
  title varchar(30) not null, 
  dept_name varchar(30) not null,  
  credits int not null,  
  constraint course_key primary key (course_id, dept_name),  
  constraint course_dept foreign key(dept_name) 
      references department on delete no action
);

create table advisor ( 
  sid char(9) not null,  
  iid char(9) not null,  
  constraint advisor_key primary key (sid, iid),  
  constraint advisor_student foreign key(sid)  
      references student on delete no action,  
  constraint advisor_instructor foreign key (iid)  
      references instructor on delete no action
);

create table prereq ( 
  course_id char(8) not null,  
  prereq_id char(8),  
  constraint prereq_key primary key (course_id),  
  constraint prereq_course foreign key(course_id)  
      references course on delete no action,  
  constraint prereq_precourse foreign key(prereq_id)  
      references course on delete no action
);

create table classroom ( 
  building varchar(30) not null,  
  room_number varchar(10) not null,  
  capicity integer,  
  constraint classroom_key primary key (building, room_number) 
);

create table time_slot ( 
  time_slot_id varchar(10) not null,  
  day varchar(10) not null,  
  start_time time not null,  
  end_time time,  
  constraint time_slot_key primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_time) 
);

create table section ( 
  course_id char(8) not null,  
  sec_id varchar(10) not null,  
  semester char(1) not null,  
  year numeric (4,0) not null,  
  building varchar(30) not null,  
  room_number varchar(10) not null,  
  time_slot_id varchar(10) not null,  
  constraint section_key primary key(course_id, sec_id, year,  
      building, room_number, time_slot_id),  
  constraint section_classroom foreign key(building, room_number)  
      references classroom on delete no action 
);

create table teaches ( 
  iid char(9) not null,  
  course_id char(8) not null,  
  sec_id varchar(10) not null,  
  semester char(1) not null,  
  year numeric(4,0) not null,  
  constraint teaches_key primary key (iid, course_id, sec_id,  
      semester, year),  
  constraint section_instrictor foreign key(iid)  
      references instructor on delete no action,  
  constraint teaches_section foreign key(course_id, sec_id, semester, year) 
      references section on delete no action 
); 

create table takes ( 
  sid char(9) not null,  
  course_id char(8) not null,  
  sec_id varchar(10) not null,  
  semester char(1) not null,  
  year numeric(4,0) not null,  
  grade real,  
  constraint takes_key primary key (sid, course_id, sec_id,  
      semester, year),  
  constraint student_takes foreign key(sid)  
      references student on delete cascade,  
  constraint takes_section foreign key(course_id, sec_id,  
      semester, year) references section on delete cascade 
);
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting. (I.e. don't include a lot of stuff not needed to reproduce the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is on your key for student. You must have the same column to join tabes whith FK. Modify you table student like this :

```
create table student (sid char(9) not null, name varchar(30) not null, tot_cred smallint, dept_name varchar(30) not null, constraint student_key primary key (sid), constraint student_dept foreign key(dept_name) references department on delete no action);
```

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020166.html) say this:

> A foreign key references a primary key or a unique key in the same or
>   another table. A foreign key assignment indicates that referential
>   integrity is to be maintained according to the specified referential
>   constraints.

Your "advisor_student" references "sid", but that is not the primary key. You would need to include the department or change the design.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary keys don't match your schema diagram for several tables.

`Instructor`, `student`, and `course` all have `dept_name` in the primary key in your DDL, but according to the Schema diagram, and logically as well, this field should not be a part of the primary key for any of those tables. In addition, the primary key of `section` does not match the Schema diagram. It should be `(course_id, sec_id, semester, year)` You have a lot of extra fields in there. That will cause problems with the foreign key constraints on `teaches` and `takes`.

Finally, the `time_slot` file both in the schema, and in the DDL have what I would call a questionable, given no other input, primary key. Should just be `time_slot_id` to my mind, then you can build a foreign key from `section` to `time_slot` as well.